# Can't login after migration assistant. No access to other account

Tags: user-account, login, migration-assistant

I was given a Mac with that had an administrator account and an account for myself (with full admin rights). Using the migration assistant, I copied everything from my old computer, however it ended up creating a new account, so I therefore deleted the new account.

I had no issues until restarting the new computer; it now no longer presents me with the new user, only the administrator account (which I don't have access to).

Is there any way I can get access to either the old account or new one without the administrator password? I've seen that this may be an issue with file vault preferences, but I can't change them if I can't log in!

Or will I just have to wait until my IT support is able to do this for me?

Comment: I have same issue, when I try to reboot with Command-R it goes straight to login window again and still won't accept the correct password. I saw another blog with instructions for single user mode to reset the password but it stops at 'Socket is not connected' …

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have resolved this by now, but if not, you can first try booting into Recovery Mode (Command-R for local version or Command-Option-R for internet version).

Once you are in, select Utilities > Utilities which will open a very plain window with a command prompt.

Here, type in "resetpassword" and press enter.

You should now be presented with a more Mac-like window to help you set/reset the password for your available accounts.

If this doesn't work, just come back and we'll try other options.